# How to match non-escaped quoted strings and also non-quoted strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a string that contains single, double, and escaped quotations:

> Telling myself 'you are  \'great\' ' and then saying "thank you" feels "a \"little\" nice"

I would like a single regex to pull out:

1. single quoted strings
2. double quoted strings
3. strings not in quotes

**Expected Result**: the following groups

1. Telling myself
2. you are  \'great\'
3. and then saying
4. thank you
5. feels
6. a \"little\" nice

*Requirements: don't return quotes, and ignore escaped quotes*

**What I have so far:**

Regex #1 to return single and double quotes ([source](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/regex-quoted-string-escapable-quotes)):

```
((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)\1
```

Result:
[image]

Regex #2 to return non-quoted strings:

```
((?<![\\])['"]|^).*?((?<![\\])['"]|$)
```

Result:
[image]

**Problems:**

1. I am unable to make regex #2 put the non-quoted string into a consistent group
2. I am unable to combine regex #1 and #2 to return all strings in one regex function

Comment: @Emma, Javascript

Comment: 6 and 7 are wrong, it should be `a \"little\" nice`

Comment: @sln, oops. Yes, you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: @Emma, I need to maintain the group requirement. I can always work the solution around using javascript, but my goal is to see if there is a javascript free solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```regex
(?<!\\)'(.+?)(?<!\\)'|(?<!\\)"(.+?)(?<!\\)"|(.+?)(?='|"|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPxhX1/3/)**.

The basic idea behind this is that it tries to match the strings with quotes first so that whatever is left after that is the strings that were not enclosed quotes. You will have all the matched strings (not including the quotes) in the capturing groups.

**Shortened version:**

```regex
(?<!\\)(['"])(.+?)(?<!\\)\1|(.+?)(?='|"|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPxhX1/4)**.

---

If you don't want to use capturing groups, you may adjust it to work with Lookarounds like the following:

```regex
(?<=(?<!\\)').+?(?=(?<!\\)')|(?<=(?<!\\)").+?(?=(?<!\\)")|(?<=^|['"]).+?(?=(?<!\\)['"]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtmMST/1)**.

**Shortened version:**

```regex
(?<=(?<!\\)(['"])).+?(?=(?<!\\)\1)|(?<=^|['"]).+?(?=(?<!\\)['"]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtmMST/2)**.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I need to ignore escaped quotes as per requirements. e.g. `you are` should not be returned, but rather `you are \'great\' `should be returned as a group.

Comment: @Wronski My bad! Fixed.

Comment: That great! It doesn't however solve the issue of putting the returned strings into consistent groups. I assume I would then need to handle this via some additional javascript.

Comment: @Wronski I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "consistent group" but I added another solution that doesn't use capturing groups so that you can just have the expected value as the whole match.

Comment: Your 2nd solution without capturing groups is . Thank you!

Comment: @Wronski I've added a shortened version of both solutions. Feel free to use the shortened or the more verbose ones.

Answer (score 1):

JS version

`/(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'|([^'"\\]+)|(\\[\S\s]))/`

https://regex101.com/r/5xfs7q/1

---

PCRE - Pro level, super version ..

`(?|(?|\s*((?:[^'"\\]|(?:\\[\S\s][^'"\\]*))+)(?<!\s)\s*|\s+(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(?<!\\)(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)')|([\S\s]))`

https://regex101.com/r/Tdyd3y/1

This is the cleanest, nicest one I've ever seen.
Wsp trim and regex contains just a single capture group.

Explained

```
 (?|                           # BReset
      (?|                           # BReset
           \s*                           # Wsp trim
           (                             # (1 start), Non-quoted data
                (?:
                     [^'"\\] 
                  |  (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'"\\]* )
                )+
           )                             # (1 end)
           (?<! \s )
           \s*                           # Wsp trim
        |                              # or,
           \s+ (*SKIP) (*FAIL)           # Skip intervals with all whitespace 
      )
   |  
      (?<! \\ )                     # Not an escape behind
      (?|                           # BReset
           " 
           (                             # (1 start), double quoted string data
                [^"\\]* 
                (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
           )                             # (1 end)
           "
        |                              # or,
           '
           (                             # (1 start), single quoted string data
                [^'\\]* 
                (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
           )                             # (1 end)
           '
      )
   |  
      ( [\S\s] )                    # (1), Pass through, single char
                                    # Un-balanced " or ' or \ at EOF
 )
```

Comment: @Wronski - No problem. I've added a pro version for PCRE if you're ever interested.